# Spring Kafka Property for setting SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Is there a spring.kafka property error handling batches

`spring.kafka.listener.type=BATCH` and
`spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=BATCH`

with **SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler** ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set it with a property, but you can override Boot's auto-configured container factory like so:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);

    factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler());

    return factory;
}
```

It will get all the boot properties and you can then further configure the factory as needed.

Comment: Thanks Gary - this really helps. Any plans to add it in the future?

Comment: I added a [new feature issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16499) to boot. It won't be a property but it could autowire in a `@Bean` if exactly one is found in the application context (like is currently done for a non-batch `ErrorHandler`).

Comment: This helps too. :)  I had noticed the autowiring the ErrorHandler Bean wasn't exactly working for a Batch. Thought I was doing something wrong. :)

Comment: Unsure if I should place the question here - Is there a reason "spring.kafka.listener.ack-on-error=false/true" feature is not implemented?

Comment: You shouldn't really; they don't like extended commentary here. It's just that there are sooooo many properties, just a few were selected, and you can always use the technique in my answer for "advanced" configuration. You could open another issue to request it against boot but they will likely not add it before 2.2 (which uses S-K 2.3 and we've switched the default to `false` there).